# Where is the convert command in macOS?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, image-processing

I need to convert a **PNG** file to an **EPS** file. Various sources on the Web refer to the `convert` command on macOS, but that program does not appear to exist on macOS High Sierra.

How do I get it?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There is no command/utility named `convert` built into macOS.

`convert` utility is installed as part of [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). You can easily install ImageMagick using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) by running:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

You can install Homebrew, using the command-line as mentioned here:

- https://github.com/Homebrew/install/blob/master/README.md#install-homebrew-on-macos-or-linux

Comment: Before that you might need to run this command `xcode-select --install`

Comment: For anyone that goes to Imagemagick's site, on the downloads screen under Mac OSX Binary Release they say "Imagemagick depends on Ghostscript fonts. To install them, type: `brew install ghostscript`". This is not necessary, `brew install imagemagick` automatically installs it.

Answer (score 4):

Once installed using @Nimesh Neema's answer you can find the location of the command by running

```
which convert
```

Comment: This should be a comment on that answer. Not an answer

Answer (score 3):

There used to be a utility in MacOS at:

```
/System/Library/Printers/convert
```

but it was removed some time ago, probably around Lion.

However, it was just a symlink to the `cupsfilter` command (though curiously it presented different flag options).

You can still use the `cupsfilter` command to convert to file types that MacOS understands, using their MIME type. The problem is that PostScript and Encapsulated PostScript share the same MIME type (`application/postscript`), and cupsfilter only outputs PostScript, rather than EPS.

EPS is a specific type of PS file, conforming to certain syntax conventions, designed for use as portable image files.

Comment: thx for the insight

Answer (score 0):

## MAMP / MAMP PRO

If you use MAMP / MAMP Pro, you have to activate the option (checkbox) in PHP tab, 'Extensions' -> Imagick / ImageMagick

And you can find binary here :

> /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/convert

Comment: This version of convert is dynamically linked and I think not easy to extract and run it outside MAMP.

Comment: For a statically linked convert, see MacTeX-2013: http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/mactex/2013/mactexadditions20130618.pkg. Open it with unpkg and find a statically linked convert at mactexadditions20130618/local/bin/convert. It's a 32-bit binary; it'll run in High Sierra and Mojave but not in Catalina and later.

Comment: See also https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx for the official binary